# Probability of tossing a coin infinitely

Tags: probability-theory

I toss and coin and stop only when I get a Tail. What's the probability of me tossing it infinitely?

Comment: Unless your name is Two-Face, ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen so that's your excuse!

Comment: Almost zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

Comment: @DougM thank you so much...I got it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of you getting n times heads in a row is $2^{-n}$ for finite experiments. The probability of getting it to infinity is just the limit as $n$ goes to infinity which is zero. It is *almost impossible* for you to keep tossing infinitely with the *almost impossible* from measure theory.

Comment: Thank you. That helps.

Comment: @DebojyotiSarkar If an answer gives satisfaction to your question, please flag it as so, using the green "tick" symbol.